# MySQL Dump only views, triggers, events and procedures

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-5.7, mysqldump, export

how are you?

I need to generate a file with all triggers, events, procedures from a server's databases and tried the two commands below

- mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases --host=127.0.0.1 --no-data
  --no-create-db --no-create-info --routines --triggers --skip-comments -- skip-opt --default-character-set=utf8 -P3306 > E:\db_objects_no_create.sql

  mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases --host=127.0.0.1 --no-data
  --no-create-db --routines --triggers --skip-comments --skip-opt --default- character-set=utf8 -P3306 > E:\db_objects.sql

In the first one, the output of the file does not extract the creation codes correctly, they are commented out.

In the second the codes are done correctly however the information of the table creation code is also exported.

Does anyone know how to do this export without the table creation code being generated in the output file?

Answer (score 2):

Include this:

```
--no-create-info
```

It means: "Do not write CREATE TABLE statements that create each dumped table." -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: he wrote he tried it already

Answer (score 0):

to ignore multiple tables, you need to exclude all one by one

Like

```
mysqldump -u root -p DB_NAME --ignore-table=DB_NAME.table1 --ignore-table=DB_NAME.table3 > database.sql
```